# Abstract nouns and action verbs

Tags: logic

I am looking for a term that defines the impossible connection of action with abstract nouns. For example, "War on Terror" (action noun- abstract noun), or "humans consume a high rate of energy" (consume - rate).

Comment: _Impossible connection_? Aspirin often relieves pain. _Impossible to explain fully_, maybe.

Comment: See [Metaphor](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf).

Comment: I am looking for a more negative term - i.e. I feel that "humans consuming rates of something" is not a logical connection

Comment: The word *rate* is used **inconsistently**. The expression might make more sense: *consume energy at a high rate*. *War on Terror* seems to be an **inconsistent** coupling of the two terms.

Answer (score 1):

[Inconsistent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inconsistent)

> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1.0 Not staying the same throughout:
>
> ...
>
> 2 (inconsistent with) Not compatible or in keeping with:

Applying this term to the two examples:

> "humans consume a high rate of energy"

Since humans don't consume rates, their is an *inconsistency* in the expression. This is likely a poor construction of the more *consistent* "humans consume energy at a high rate."

> *War on terror*

A *war on terrorists* would be a clearly a *consistent* phrase. People execute war on other people. *War on terror* might be considered inconsistent unless you recognize the [metaphorical](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf) use of the word *war* in the expression.

www.oxforddictionaries.com

http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf